# How to get the max value in list then labeled it in PYTHON?

Tags: python

i got the result after calculating with fuzzy c means

how can i get the max value every list in list?
how can i labeled the max value?

i use cluster=3

here the result :

```
[[0.03740738448970282, 0.9201270778103205, 0.04246553769997666], //the max is 0.92012.. then labeled as C2 
[0.04062653809163984, 0.0238461204483894, 0.93552734145997075], //the max is 0.93552.. then labeled as C3
[0.9479964560714227, 0.010597386771375585, 0.0414061571572017], etc..
[0.37614962184288964, 0.44114302923190574, 0.18270734892520468], 
[0.20274562875747867, 0.4228700262497846, 0.37438434499273676], 
[0.8083572028927598, 0.05195626129940783, 0.1396865358078323], 
[0.05128850852899145, 0.02388543639574726, 0.9248260550752613], 
[0.9002477815473989, 0.03596599813260756, 0.06378622031999359], 
[0.22219257479765195, 0.06316371301545853, 0.7146437121868896], 
[0.05107621048105372, 0.9111492746104877, 0.03777451490845857]]
```

i expect the result :

C2

C3

C1

C2

C2

etc..

if cluster = 4
so the labeled will till C4

Comment: Where do you want to save the labeled list and max value?

Comment: Please check my answer. The others are similar, so it's up to you to choose. Don't forget to upvote them and accept an answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
liste = [[0.03740738448970282, 0.9201270778103205, 0.04246553769997666],
[0.04062653809163984, 0.0238461204483894, 0.93552734145997075],
[0.9479964560714227, 0.010597386771375585, 0.0414061571572017],
[0.37614962184288964, 0.44114302923190574, 0.18270734892520468],
[0.20274562875747867, 0.4228700262497846, 0.37438434499273676],
[0.8083572028927598, 0.05195626129940783, 0.1396865358078323],
[0.05128850852899145, 0.02388543639574726, 0.9248260550752613],
[0.9002477815473989, 0.03596599813260756, 0.06378622031999359],
[0.22219257479765195, 0.06316371301545853, 0.7146437121868896],
[0.05107621048105372, 0.9111492746104877, 0.03777451490845857]]

result = ['C'+str(l.index(max(l))+1) for l in liste]
```

```
result
Out: ['C2', 'C3', 'C1', 'C2', 'C2', 'C1', 'C3', 'C1', 'C3', 'C2']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [[0.03740738448970282, 0.9201270778103205, 0.04246553769997666],.....,[0.05107621048105372, 0.9111492746104877, 0.03777451490845857]]

for i in arr:
    print('C'+str(i.index(max(i))+1))
```

Output:-

```
C2
C3
C1
C2 ........ etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Output as requested.

```
lsts =([[0.03740738448970282, 0.9201270778103205, 0.04246553769997666],  # the max is 0.92012.. then labeled as C2 
[0.04062653809163984, 0.0238461204483894, 0.93552734145997075], # the max is 0.93552.. then labeled as C3
[0.9479964560714227, 0.010597386771375585, 0.0414061571572017], # etc..
[0.37614962184288964, 0.44114302923190574, 0.18270734892520468], 
[0.20274562875747867, 0.4228700262497846, 0.37438434499273676], 
[0.8083572028927598, 0.05195626129940783, 0.1396865358078323], 
[0.05128850852899145, 0.02388543639574726, 0.9248260550752613], 
[0.9002477815473989, 0.03596599813260756, 0.06378622031999359], 
[0.22219257479765195, 0.06316371301545853, 0.7146437121868896], 
[0.05107621048105372, 0.9111492746104877, 0.03777451490845857]])


for lst in lsts:
    index_max = lst.index(max(lst))+1
    print("C" + str(index_max))
    # print(f"C{index_max}") # Python 3.6+
```

Yield

```
C2
C3
C1
C2
C2
C1
C3
C1
C3
C2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a huge dataset, sth like numpy would be nice to use. If it is a small set, the list comprehensions like above should be fine.

```py
import numpy as np
lsts =([[0.03740738448970282, 0.9201270778103205, 0.04246553769997666],
[0.04062653809163984, 0.0238461204483894, 0.93552734145997075], 
[0.9479964560714227, 0.010597386771375585, 0.0414061571572017],
[0.37614962184288964, 0.44114302923190574, 0.18270734892520468], 
[0.20274562875747867, 0.4228700262497846, 0.37438434499273676], 
[0.8083572028927598, 0.05195626129940783, 0.1396865358078323], 
[0.05128850852899145, 0.02388543639574726, 0.9248260550752613], 
[0.9002477815473989, 0.03596599813260756, 0.06378622031999359], 
[0.22219257479765195, 0.06316371301545853, 0.7146437121868896], 
[0.05107621048105372, 0.9111492746104877, 0.03777451490845857]])
a = np.asarray(lsts)
for x in a.argmax(axis=1):
    print("C" + str(x+1))
```

Output:

```
C2
C3
C1
C2
C2
C1
C3
C1
C3
C2
```